# A great way to control global variables

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, lazy-static, embedded-control

I'm trying to develop a web backend + embedded controller, but I'm having difficulty controlling global variables.
When starting an application, declare a global variable or a list (containing objects) and call the web API to access the global variable and change the contents of the variable or look up the variable.

I started with the two approaches below.

1. Use : lazy_static + Mutex

   ```
   lazy_static! {
       pub static ref ROBOT_LIST: Mutex<Vec<Robot>> = Mutex::new(vec![
           Robot {id: 1, name: String::from("robot1"), pos_x: 1, pos_y: 1, speed: 0, direction: 0}
       ]
           );
       }
   ```
2. Use : OnceLock

   ```
   static mut ROBOT_LIST: OnceLock<Vec<Robot>> = OnceLock::new();
   ```

But neither works well.
When api call data not changes or async api doesn't work anything (cant debug also...)

Below is pseudo code what I want to implemented

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Robot {
    pub id: usize,
    pub name: String,
    pub pos_x: i32,
    pub pos_y: i32,
    pub speed: i32,
    pub direction: i32,
}
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref ROBOT_LIST: Mutex<Vec<Robot>> = Mutex::new(vec![
        Robot {id: 1, name: String::from("robot1"), pos_x: 1, pos_y: 1, speed: 0, direction: 0}
    ]
        );
    }
```

**API 1:** start sim-controller for attacking Object

```
pub fn sim(){
actix_rt::spawn(async move {

            unsafe{
                let mut robot_now = ROBOT_LIST.lock().unwrap();
                let mut robot1: &mut Robot = &mut robot_now.get_mut(0).unwrap();
    
                loop {
                    sleep(Duration::new(1, 0)).await;
    
                    if robot1.direction == 0 {
                        println!("x pos : {}, y pos {}", robot1.pos_x, robot1.pos_y);
                        continue;
                    } else if robot1.direction == 1 {
                        //x-axis
                        robot1.pos_x += robot1.speed;
                    } else if robot1.direction == 2 {
                        //y-axis
                        robot1.pos_y += robot1.speed;
                    }
    
                    println!("x pos : {}, y pos {}", robot1.pos_x, robot1.pos_y);
                    
                }
            }
    
        });

}
```

**API 2:** Order to move Object

```
pub fn move_robot(){
    unsafe{
        let mut robot_now = ROBOT_LIST.lock().unwrap();
        let mut robot1: &mut Robot = robot_now.get_mut(0).unwrap();
        robot1.speed = -1;
        //0 : stop
        //1 : x-axis
        //2 : y-axis
        robot1.direction = 1;
    }
    

}
```

Please recommend a method that does not cause problems when accessing global variables in the above manner or please recommend a way to control global variables in Rust reliably and without problems.

Embedded controllers were implemented without problems in higher-level languages ​​such as Python.

Comment: Global variables are just a terrible idea to start with. Can you avoid them here? One thing to consider when using Tokio is to give complete control over certain variables to a task, and then communicate with that via messages, e.g. MPSC or otherwise.

Comment: It's not clear to me why a global mutex wouldn't work. It's not _ideal,_ but you haven't explained why that approach was problematic.

Comment: @tadman 
From what I understand, MPSC seems to manage messages in order. What I want is to manage objects globally, but how can I use message emitting to implement the pattern I want?

Comment: @cdhowie 
When i start sim thread and call move robot api then robot1 object doesnt change anything..., when i debuging that thread is stop when i call move api(i think because that api get ROBOT_LIST ownership) but anything not change

Comment: @이경서 You can't move out of a mutex (without doing something like `std::mem::take`). You would need to show some sample code for us to determine why it's not working, because [mutexes definitely work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4ae05e3c9adcc302acbe70fd4752e6fe).

Comment: @cdhowie
I dont know that is share ablout rust playground 
It is a collection of code fragments. This method calls two APIs in order.
[src](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f01f4b8f691842d2b0b276e84fa30229)

Comment: @이경서 I'm still not sure what the problem with the code is as you haven't described the behavior you're seeing, the exact steps that cause that behavior, and the behavior you want to see instead. Also, note the `unsafe` blocks are completely unnecessary. You should almost never use `unsafe` and there should be a very good reason for doing so. Nothing in this code requires `unsafe`.

Comment: @cdhowie

Let me explain the order more clearly.

Comment: @cdhowie
First, when you run the app with cargo run, the actix-web app runs. 
After that, when /startsim is executed with the get method, 
the sim() function runs an infinite loop that displays the location while searching ROBOT_LIST. 
Afterwards, when /moverobot is executed with the get method, 
the move_robot() function is called and the information of the first robot object 
in ROBOT_LIST is changed.

Comment: @cdhowie
In that case, when the infinite loop of the sim() function searches ROBOT_LIST, 
the information of robot number 1 has changed, 
so the location of robot number 1 must change. But it doesnt work...

Comment: You `sim` function locks the mutex when it starts _and never releases it._ As a consequence your `move` function can never lock the mutex and blocks immediately. You should move the `ROBOT_LIST.lock()` line after the `sleep` line in `sim`.

Comment: @Jmb
OMG, really thx!! it is working now....
In Rust, when accessing a global variable, if you access it from one place and take ownership, does it have to be released in order to access it?

Comment: @이경서 in any programming language, when accessing a shared variable through a mutex, if you access it in one place you need to release it before you can access it in another place. This is not specific to Rust, nor to global variables: it's the same in C/C++, Java, Python, C# and all multithread languages with mutexes. And it's the same if you share the variable with an `Arc<Mutex<…>>` or a `&Mutex<…>` instead of a global variable.